# VIsual Studio 2017 C++: How can I programmatically select code page 1252 (english), 932 (Shift JIS, Japanese) and 65001 (UTF-8, multi-lingual)?

Tags: utf-8, visual-studio-2019, multilingual

I want to support code page 1252 (english), 932 (Shift JIS, Japanese), and code page 65001 (UTF-8), but SetThreadUILanguage(65001) fails and returns 1033 (0x409). If I compile with a manifest, I can use code page 65001.

My example tries to display the Euro sign with code page 65001. Works with a manifest, does not work without. Our customers have lots of code page 932 files, so I'd like to be able to switch on-the-fly.
Example code here:

https://github.com/markmenge/UTF8.git

I tried calling SetThreadUILanguage(65001) in CWinApp constructor, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can't use `CP_UTF8` (65001) in most APIs unless you explicitly opt-in to UTF-8 support at the OS level, via an [`activeCodePage` app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page). UTF-8 support at the OS level is a relatively new feature, so you have to opt-in, you don't get it automatically. That being said, you don't need UTF-8 support at the OS level in order to process non-UTF8 files. Nothing stops you from converting non-UTF8 data to UTF-16 (Windows native Unicode encoding) for display purposes.

Comment: Thanks Remy, do you think I should be able to start with a manifest, and code page 65001, and somehow change to e.g. code page 932?

Comment: Why do you think you need UTF-8 to work with cp932?

Comment: Up to this point, the user has to choose a single language character set, i.e. code page, in windows, which is a real pain. I think if you pick UTF8, then you can show English, Chinese, Japanese etc, all the languages side-by-side which is huge deal. Somehow notepad++ is able to switch on-the-fly between particular character sets and UTF-8. Also UTF-8 is compatible with the C standard libraries which is what our 400 executables use.

Comment: You don't need UTF-8 at the OS level (or even at all) to handle the task you have described.

Comment: Fantastic news! Setting this checkbox "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" means our 400 multibyte executables are now mult-lingual AND we have one API for Unix and Windows!  See https://github.com/markmenge/UTF8/blob/main/HowToUseUTF8.png for details how to set it.  The only small downside is that users have to reboot and use a Beta feature (but presumably that will go into release soon).

Comment: Ah crud, more testing shows that copying and pasting the € symbol between notepad.exe and the test executable transforms the character into something else when compiled without the manifest. Interestingly the exe with the manifest seems to work well. I guess declaring victory was premature.